# Bootstrap 3 Selectbox - Clickable only on Arrow

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using Bootstrap Selectbox. For some reason, I have to use selectpicker inside anchor tag and restrict clicking on entire button and should be clickable only on arrow? On clicking on the dropdown arrow, list will be visible. Other places I have to ignore the click event.

Please check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qq70tdgc/)

```
<a href="#">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
        <option>Plain</option>
        <option>Steamed</option>
        <option>Toasted</option>
    </select>
</a>
```

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this workaround!!

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qq70tdgc/1/)**

```
$('button.dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(e){
    if($(e.target).attr('class')!="caret")
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```